# What is an Extension Class?

Tags: c#, .net

My teacher asked us to investigate what an Extension Class was but I can't seem to find anything on MSDN or Google. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean extension methods? Don't think Extension classes exist in C# unless you are refering to derived classes?

Comment: Are you sure that it was "extension class" and not "extension method"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no such thing as "extension class" in formal C# terminology. It might mean a class defining [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) (which is not anything special, it's just a simple `static` class.)

Answer (score 7):

Your teacher may also be talking about [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx)...

Answer (score 5):

Technically an "extension class" is not anything. In the vernacular it could be used by someone to refer to a class that is designed to store [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx?ppud=4). Extension methods are methods used to look like instance methods of a class, but which are truly static methods in a static class that are provided to enhance and encapsulate certain functionality. They are especially useful when you are trying to extend certain functionality on a type that you cannot modify directly and add a method to. Additionally, they are often used with generic types (especially within the .net 3.5 framework) to extend functionality using the methods provided by a specific interface.

Answer (score 2):

A class that has [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

> Extension methods enable you to "add"
>   methods to existing types without
>   creating a new derived type,
>   recompiling, or otherwise modifying
>   the original type. Extension methods
>   are a special kind of static method,
>   but they are called as if they were
>   instance methods on the extended type.
>   For client code written in C# and
>   Visual Basic, there is no apparent
>   difference between calling an
>   extension method and the methods that
>   are actually defined in a type.

Answer (score 1):

An Extension class in C# could simply be a child class( inheriting and adding more functionality to the base type or interface) or a static class.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know extension class is there .But extension method is there .
Try this 
[Extension Method](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little bit older but one thing that came to my mind when I read this question is the refactoring book by Martin fowler. In  Chapter 7 **Moving Features Between Objects**, he describes a refactoring called **Introduce Local Extension** . There he talks about creation an **extension class** which is nothing more or less than a subclass or a wrapper around an object. The purpose of this extension class is to extend the functionality of an existing class like `Date` (The Java class `Date` not the `DateTime` class of .Net which is in fact sealed).

Some of the other answers here refered to the **extension Method** which seems to be another way of using the refactoring **Introduce foreign Method**. I am not sure about this, so I maybe mistaken here.

I think the book was written in 1999 with most examples in Java so maybe this doesn't relate so much to .Net but I guess the concept is universal.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to an Extension Class that I can come up with is for example Microsoft's ExceptionExtensions class.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff654014(v=pandp.10)

If you create your own method in a class with that name, it becomes accessible from the Exception object.

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static String myMethod(this Exception ex)
    {
        return ("Hi!");
    }
}
```

Access it this way:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    String message = ex.myMethod();
}
```